# Using RegExp to dynamically create a Regular Expression, and filter content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom-manipulation

I am struggling with using the `RegExp` object to allow me to dynamically create an expression, and apply it to a group of elements.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2R8Wq/4/), below is the code:

```
<div id='selectors'><span>A-F</span><span>G-L</span><span>M-S</span><span>T-Z</span></div>

<a hreh=#>Astring</a>
<a hreh=#>Cstring</a>
<a hreh=#>Xstring</a>
<a hreh=#>Dstring</a>
<a hreh=#>Zstring</a>

$('div#selectors span').click(function(){
        expression = "/^["+$(this).html()+"].*$/";

        rx = RegExp(expression,'i');
        console.log(rx,'expression');
        $("a").each(function(){

                    if($(this).html().match(rx) !== null){
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                    }
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

JavaScript automatically adds "/" at the end and the beginning of the expression. Remove them from your string, **[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2R8Wq/50/)**

```
$('div#selectors span').click(function () {
    var expression = "^[" + $(this).html() + "].*$";
    var rx = new RegExp(expression, 'i');

    console.log(rx, 'expression');

    $("a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html().match(rx) !== null) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: More accurately, the `/` denote a regex literal but are not part of it,  like `"` denotes a string literal, but is not part of the string.

Comment: Don't forget when the regular expression uses \ slashes, to escape those to \\